# Recursive Binary Tree Insert in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

So I am trying to learn how to create a binary tree in C so far I have got this.

```
void addRecordsToTree(struct date *in, struct date *root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
        root = in;
        return;
    } else { 
        //Right side of tree processing
        if (compareTwoRecords(in, root) >= 0) {
            addRecordsToTree(in, root->right);
            return;
        } else {
            root->right = in;
            return;
        }
        //Left side of tree processing.
        if (compareTwoRecords(in, root) < 0) {
            addRecordsToTree(in, root->left);
            return;
        } else {
            root->left = in;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    loadFiles();
    struct date treeRoot;
    struct date *old = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    old = loadContentsIntoHeap(files[file2014]);

    addRecordsToTree(&old[0], &treeRoot);
    addRecordsToTree(&old[1], &treeRoot);
    addRecordsToTree(&old[2], &treeRoot);
    addRecordsToTree(&old[3], &treeRoot);
    addRecordsToTree(&old[4], &treeRoot);
    addRecordsToTree(&old[5], &treeRoot);

    printRecord(7, old);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I check the state of the program in a debugger there is just jumbled up data. I think it could be a type problem somewhere, I find pointers are bit of a mind boggling concept. Im not sure if I have used them right. So here is a screen shot of the debugger.

[image: debugger shot of last addRecordsToTree() call]

As you can see at the bottom struct called 'old' is the data I am trying to make the tree out of and treeRoot is where I am trying to place it but I can't understand why I get these garbage values.

Also what is up with the memory address of left and right? am I not creating them correctly.

Another observation I made is when I watch my code in the debugger it seems that root is never == NULL and never gets set, why?

Comment: `root = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
        root = in;` - So you are allocating memory, and then just leaking it away by reassigning the same pointer..

Comment: That part never runs.

Comment: Anyway, your code paste lacks *critical* parts. Like allocations and initializations.

Answer (score 1):

You just did the following:

```
int x = 2;
int y = x;
y = 5;
```

Is the second line here necessary or the third one. It is a totally illogical program if you did this. You just did the same thing with a pointer instead of integer. You firstly had a pointer to the base address of dynamic memory then you just overwrote it by initializing it the second time.

And, the iterative approach is far better in comparison to the recursive one. I share the code for inserting a node in a binary tree both recursively and iteratively:

```
void insert(struct node *temp, struct node **root)
{
    while (*root != NULL)
        root = (*root)->element < temp->element ? &(*root)->left : &(*root)->right;
    *root = temp;
}

#if 0
/* Recursive approach */
void insert(struct node *temp, struct node **root)
{
    if(*root == NULL)
        *root = temp;
    else if ((*root)->element < temp->element)
        insert(temp, &(*root)->left);
    else
        insert(temp, &(*root)->right);
}
#endif

void create_node(int x, struct node **root)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp == NULL)
        printf("Unable to allocate memory. Free some space.\n");
    else
    {
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->element = x;
        insert(temp, root);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = NULL;
    create_node(1, &root);
    create_node(2, &root);
    create_node(3, &root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is iteration far better than recursion? I find it easier to read and it probably has the same performance.

Comment: Just one thing about recursion: stack overflow. Thats a different topic.

Comment: You should apply it only if the iterative approach is too shaby or takes longer than the recursive one. If both options have same time complexity then you should always follow the iterative one. I may have used not so used the so called `double pointer` usage in modifying linked objects. It is generally more tougher to understand but a more general approach. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiAhUYCUDVc

Answer (score 0):

I saw an additional Problem in your "addRecordsToTree"-function:

the IF-block of the

"//Right side of tree processing"

will allways return from the function. regardless wether the "IF"-Expression is true or false.
So your left-leaves of thew tree will never be inserted. So you probalby should check/debug that function.

Comment: Yes that was my intention because it calls itself it would never reach the return because the recursive call is in the way, it is only once it reached the point of insertion it would return from the stack frame and then return. The else is just an assignment and once assigned it can return. That was my noob logic anyway